# DSC strategy for removing unknown local users

Tags: dsc

I'm pursuing DSC as a lightweight solution for managing local user accounts on distributed Windows instances in favour of connecting said instances to Active Directory.

Adding and removing specified local users works as expected, but I also want to check that ONLY the specified accounts exist (or are enabled) on each configured node.

e.g. - If I were to create a new local admin account with 'xUser CreateUserAccount / Ensure = Present', if I were to remove the code from my DSC script, that user would still exist on the target node. Similarly, if someone were to create a local user account by some other means, there would be no warning of the unexpected configuration drift through the DSC server.

To remove any unexpected accounts, I would first need be made aware of these accounts by some other means, and then specify 'xUser RemoveUserAccount'.

I have not found a way around this with the first 100 Google results on the topic. Has anyone solved this apparent conundrum with DSC? Should I rather look to something else e.g. Terraform?

Comment: You could use the script resource, to specify some powershell script to look for if there has been added any other users than what you want in the test part, and then in the set part add some script to remove those. I would believe that might be the easiest way to get around this.

Comment: Thanks - I did briefly consider scripting something with the script resource, but it just looked unnecessarily difficult to parse the "test" definitions. My intention here was to create single document in source control that defines all user rights - DSC is already sub-optimal due to its verbosity ...

Comment: Well another way, could be to create your own resource that could handle a list of user rights or see if anyone else has made something in that aspect.
You can check this [github repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/DscResources) out